# Unstable behaviour of google maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am receiving an unstable behaviour of google maps API, but the surprising thing is that is only happing with a single example I am using in my unit tests, all the others are working ok.

Essentially I implemented a get call to the following address:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=es&address=La%20Asunci%C3%B3n,%20Herrera%20De%20Duero,%20Valladolid,%20Spain

So, it is a unit test, and I know this result shall give an error ouput, so the expected behaviour is the following:

{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

However, from time to time this results is not provided and I am getting the following one:

{'error_message': 'You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_', 'results': [], 'status': 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'}

Ok, the first thing I thought is that I am over the daily quota... but this actually is not the case, as I mentioned before this is part of the unittesting of my code, and after this call I have another one that works... if I wait some time, let's say, 10 minutes, comes back and provides me the right input.

So essentially I am experiencing an unstable behaviour. My questions to this forum is that if somebody has experienced the same issue and how you have been able to overcome the issue, implementing a "re-try" mechanism has not worked for me and I am out of ideas.

Comment: Does your call that "works" include a key?  Or is this the 10th or 11th query in a row (maybe you are hitting the rate limit)?

Comment: Is not including a key, is essentially a get call to the address I provided. I thought as well the rate limit, but, it is always in the same location and independently if I run the unittest alone or in a group. The rate limit is 50 and I am below that limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google slowly but steadily is deprecating the keyless access to web services. If you don't use an API key you can hit a global quota established for Geocoding API web service. This global quota is quite low, so you can see error messages from time to time.

Generate an API key and use it with the unit test requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Note that previously the keyless access was deprecated for Google Maps JavaScript API

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

I hope this helps!

#### Update

With introduction of [Google Maps Platform](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html) in June 2018 the keyless access was deprecated for all services. You must use API keys with Google Maps APIs from now on.

> Beginning June 11, you’ll need a valid API key and a Google Cloud Platform billing account to access our core products.